# Lambda are allowed at source level only 1.8 or above

Tags: java, eclipse

I have Eclipse version 1.8 (mars .2 version) and I have compliance-java level set to 1.8 as shown below.

[image]

but I am still getting error: "Lambda are allowed at source level only 1.8 or above".

Comment: What gives you that error? Eclipse shouldn't do that for the "ams" project.

Comment: I dint get you..can you come once again

Comment: Is it really eclipse showing this error (like http://i.stack.imgur.com/iXWuq.png for example) or some external tool? And is it really the "ams" project that gives you that error? Eclipse shouldn't give you that error because the "Source compatibility: 1.8" option is exactly what controls this. You could try if cleaning the project gets rid of the problem ("Project > Clean..." in the menu).

Comment: Yes exactly as you shared the pic similar way i am getting the error through eclipse

Comment: If cleaning doesn't help, try setting to down to 1.7, then back up to 1.8.

Comment: cleaning up the project helped me.Thank you for the solution

Answer (score 5):

You also nend to set your Java Build path in your project.
[image: You also nend to set your Java Build path]

Comment: Yup i have done.and i have the jre system librart 1.8 in it.