# Pass function to a method and then use that function in another method

Tags: java

The title might confuse you, but here's what I am asking for.

I have 2 classes: `Parser` and `CommandArray`.

In the `CommandArray` I want to have a function that will add a command to my array, and look a little bit like this: `addCommand(String name, [Type] callback)`. Then in the `Parser` I want to have that `CommandArray`, so the `Parser` can loop through an array of strings, find the `name`, parse that line, then if everything is correct, run `callback` and pass the line to it.

Here's some pseudocode to illustrate what I'm trying to do a little better:

```
myCallback = function(line)
  print(line)
end

function parseLine(command, callback) -- command is the line
  -- do the parsing
  callback(command)
end

parseLine("Rectangle 32, 32, 64, 64", myCallback)
```

Disclaimer: This code wasn't tested

Is there any easy way to do it in Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not 100% sure what your end result is but you can accomplish this with the use of functional interfaces.

A quick example:

The code below would be the equivalent of your pseudocode:

```
Consumer<String> myCallback = System.out::println;
```

then the parseLine function will become:

```
public void parseLine(String command, Consumer<String> callback){
       callback.accept(command);
}
```

then this line:

```
parseLine("Rectangle 32, 32, 64, 64", myCallback)
```

will become:

```
parseLine("Rectangle 32, 32, 64, 64", myCallback);
```

for more information about all the available functional interfaces and what you can do with them check out the **[java.util.function](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html)** package.

Comment: It looks like this is totally what I'm looking for, thank you for your answer.

Comment: Now I am testing it, but with an array of strings instead. I have a function that accepts an array of strings as its parameters in my main class, but I don't know how to call it. `this::myFunction` doesn't work. The error I'm getting is `Method references are allowed only at source level 1.8 or above`

Comment: try cleaning up your project and if that doesn't work then you might also need to set your Java Build path in your project. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37628789/lamba-are-allowed-at-source-level-only-1-8-or-above .